# Where is Stan sampling from?

Tags: bayesian, stan

I found a link that shows a simple Stan model for linear regression:

```
data {
 int < lower = 1 > N; // Sample size
 vector[N] x; // Predictor
 vector[N] y; // Outcome
}

parameters {
 real alpha; // Intercept
 real beta; // Slope (regression coefficients)
 real < lower = 0 > sigma; // Error SD
}

model {
 y ~ normal(alpha + x * beta , sigma);
}
```

The `model` section just looks like the likelihood function. Does that mean Stan just generates sample of `alpha` and `beta` from the likelihood function?

Comment: The sampling syntax `~` is purely evocative. The stan documentation describes how HMC works in great detail, and explains how the syntax and model construction works.

Comment: One thing that's very confusing about this model is that there's no priors on the parameters. Is your question in regards to the lack of priors?

Comment: @CliffAB if no priors are mentioned, Stan assumes flat priors with the support defined in variables definition, e.g. non-negative values on real line with equal probability for sigma.

Comment: @ReinstateMonica can you direct me towards where in the Stan documentation they take about this? I saw this [page](https://mc-stan.org/docs/2_19/reference-manual/sampling.html) on sampling but it doesn't mention how Stan combines the prior and the likelihood to do the sampling.

Comment: https://mc-stan.org/docs/2_21/reference-manual/hamiltonian-monte-carlo.html The posterior distribution is the target density $p(\theta)$, which is implicitly coded as the stan program.